# Creating an imageslider using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to create a imageslider using javascript. I have found this [script](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/js/jcarousellite_1.0.1.min.js). But I can't find tooltip in this. I want to do exactly like in this [website](http://books.google.com/). I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

How about [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) for the tooltips?